# Networks-security-related

Tags: security, networking, router, packet-sniffers

It doesn't relate specifically to any programming language or technique, but still: 
You know how you can use programs like Wireshark to read packets going through your computer (or router, more accurately)? These packets can contain secret information that must be encrypted somehow, like username and password for some systems. But even without this information, one can recreate these packets and obtain the same information, no? For example, I can send these packets from my computer, pretend that I've requested the service and obtain access that way to the given system. How is that prevented?

Also, a kind-of-related question: when a router receives a packet, how does it know to which computer to direct it to if multiple computers are connected to it in an LAN?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called a [replay-attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) - to prevent this sort of attack the respective protocol needs to have some built-in features (like some unique ID per request and becomes invalid after being received the very first time and/or becomes invalid after a certain amount of time and/or some timestamp etc.).

Comment: @DimenShaw a router knows this because the so-called MAC-address ("HW"-adress of the NIC, source and destination) is part of the Ethernet frame (physical layer) which in turns contains the IP packet...